# Formation des questions - interrogation complexe

Tags: grammaire, questions

I just want to make sure I understood this.

The following sentence does not belong to the *langue soutenue* :

> Comment s'appelle-t-il, ton copain ?

The "more correct" way of saying this would be:

> Comment ton copain s'appelle-t-il ?

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

- Comment c'est qu'il s'appelle ton copain ? (*c'est dit,  considéré comme pas élégant*)
- Comment c'est que ton copain s'appelle ? (*c'est dit,  considéré comme pas élégant*)
- Il s'appelle comment ton copain ? (*courant*, pas trop élégant mais pas vulgaire)
- Comment il s'appelle, ton copain ? (*courant, mais légèrement lourd*)
- Comment s'appelle ton copain ? (*courant*)
- **Comment s'appelle-t-il, ton copain ?** (*courant, et correct lorsque « ton copain » est utilisé après une très légère pause en tant que précision, de façon a assurer la compréhension de l'interlocuteur ; mais dans ce cas il s'agit plutôt de « Comment s'appelle-t-il ? Ton copain ? ».*)
- **Comment ton copain s'appelle-t-il ?** (*moins courant, parler plus élégant*)

Comment: Donc la dernière phrase est la plus élégante ?

Comment: Il me semble que c'est légèrement mieux que la 6e mais, personnellement, je n'insisterais pas sur une utilisation exclusive de la 7e ; la 6e et la 7e sont surtout plus élégantes que les 4 premières et la 5e est d'un style similaire à celui de la 6e et de la 7e.